# Node.js sqlite UPDATE not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, discord, discord.js

**If you have knowledge of Discord.js or any other Discord JS libraries then you will have a better understanding on what I'm asking.**

So I'm trying to `UPDATE` a record in my database to a string of text assigned to a variable `WHERE` the ID = the ID assigned to the message's guild.

**Here is my code,**

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
sql.get(`SELECT * FROM guildconfig WHERE guildID = "${message.guild.id}`).then((row) => {
    if(!row) {
        sql.run("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS guildconfig (guildID INTEGER, prefix TEXT)").then(() => {
            sql.run("INSERT INTO guildconfig (guildID, prefix) VALUES (?, ?)", [message.guild.id, guildprefix]);
        });
    } else {
        sql.run(`UPDATE guildconfig SET prefix = ${guildprefix} WHERE guildID = ${message.guild.id}`);
    }
}).catch(() => {
    console.error;
});
```

---

As you probably guessed `guildconfig` is the name of the table.

`message.guild.id` is constant that is assigned to the guild/server that the message was sent in.

`guildconfig` is an argument passed in the message.

Comment: What doesn't work?  What is the error message?

Comment: It just doesn't work, their is no error message, when I view the database their is no change made to the entry.

I've edited the post to include more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like you've just forgotten to wrap quotes around the ID in your query i.e. `guildID = "${message.guild.id}"`, you appear to do this in your `SELECT` query (although presumably you've made a typo as you aren't closing the quotes).

So, ironically, I didn't need to know anything about Discord, just SQL :)